# How to update a nested sobject using simple_salesforce?

Tags: python, salesforce

I have been trying to update a nested object using `simple_salesforce` specifically been trying to update the `Owner` field in a `Case` object.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username = 'username',password = 'password',security_token='security_token', sandbox = False)

sf.Case.create({'Description':'stuff in description','Owner':'Owners User'})
```

Whenever I try to insert I get the following error:

Response content:

```
[{u'errorCode': u'INVALID_FIELD', u'message': u'The value provided for foreign key reference Owner is not a nested SObject'}]
```

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same error and it turns out you have to use the `OwnerId` field and pass the Id of the owner.

Comment: I had a similar error and fix.  The error was The value provided for foreign key reference RecordType is not a nested SObject.  And the fix was to send RecordTypeId

Comment: @nomadic_squirrel - how to use this if both objects are new / unsynced and no object id is available?

Comment: @Tobonaut, I think you'd have to insert the parent first, then pass the id?

Comment: @nomadic_squirrel I think so, too. But this adds a new high complexity layer to the application. It has 20+ Objets and most of them has 5+ treatable lookup values. I thought, that the SDK would make it easier.

Comment: Just to point out that this is an extremely annoying "feature" of salesforce... There are many such standard relationship fields that you need to add "Id" in the end of the field name. The problem is that the UI shows those fields API Names without  "Id" in the name and it's very confusing :/ Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I ran into this also for the Lead nested sObject in the task object.  It turns out all I had to do was change 'Who' to 'WhoId'.  vals['WhoId'] = lead_id

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with setting the Opportunity RecordType - I was trying to use the "text" of the Type name.  However, you have to pass the 15 digit SF name of the Record Type, to find that, you need to go to SETUP, Opportunities, RecordTypes, click Edit by your record type, and in the URL you will see a the value:

https://----------.cs44.my.salesforce.com/setup/ui/recordtypefields.jsp?id=01215000001UUtL&type=Opportunity&setupid=OpportunityRecords

The value you pass in the above example is: '01215000001UUtL'

Your Simple-Salesforce Call would look like:

sf.opportunity.create({'RecordTypeId':"01215000001UUtL",'AccountId':SFaccountId,'CloseDate':SFcloseDate,'StageName':'Closed Won','Name':'OPPORTUNITY NAME'})